# Minishift Error: Error getting migrated host: unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: minishift

I am unable to start, stop or delete minishift on Windows. I have been able to start it and use it successfully before, but I did a `minishift delete` without stopping the minishift cluster first with `minishift stop`. Now I can't get minishift to start because I keep getting this error:

```
PS C:\Users\user01> minishift version
minishift v1.20.0+53c500a
PS C:\Users\user01> minishift start
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
Error getting migrated host: unexpected end of JSON input
```

Most commands give me this error now:
**Error getting migrated host: unexpected end of JSON input**

```
> minishift docker-env
Error getting migrated host: unexpected end of JSON input
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that some configuration files got corrupted, even though `minishift delete` should be safe using without stopping it first. What does execution of `minishift status` return?

Anyway, first, you can try using `minishift delete --force` which deletes all vm specific files in minishift home (~/.minishift). If does not help, continue with next steps.

Second, the way how to restore and start minishift again from fresh is to delete directory with configuration files. It is usually placed at ~/.minishift unless you have set MINISHIFT_HOME env. variable which could changes this location. Also, I usually delete ~/.kube folder. Then start minishift again, everything should be created from scratch.

Finally, new version of minishift (1.21) got released, you may try that as well.

Note that if you have used any persistent configuration you will lose it with removing minishift home folder, so back up all necessary stuff.